# Generics: Abstract class and type of child

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have an abstract class called presenter:

```java
abstract class Presenter<V> {

    fun bind(view: V) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And I have implementations of these presenters:

```java
class FolderChooserPresenter : Presenter<FolderChooserView>() {
    ...
}
```

And view classes which call the bind method at a specified point:

```java
class FolderChooserActivity : BaseView(), FolderChooserView {

    @Inject lateinit var presenter: FolderChooserPresenter

    // method of baseview
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        presenter.bind(this)
    }
}
```

What I would like to archieve is to have a base class for classes like the `FolderChooserActivity` which automatically call the bind method.
It feels stupid to repeat these calls over and over again in all implementations.

My approach is to have an abstract class which extends the `BaseView` which calls the bind method. But that obviously does not work as the bind class requires the implementation and not the abstract class.

Comment: `FolderChooserView` is an interface, and do all view interfaces have a common ancestor interface?

Comment: Adding the `android` tag might help if this is a common issue in the Android class hierarchies, someone else might have solved it.  Likely if solved with Java generics, it would be the same solution for Kotlin.  You might want to ask it with the `java` tag as well and then edit the question to say for Java or Kotlin how would you solve this problem with generics while avoiding a possible runtime unchecked cast.  It doesn't need to be limited to Kotlin.

Comment: Yes it is an interface. No they don't have a common ancestor interface. But if that would solve the problem and get around casting that is an option.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem actually, you would be casting from the ancestor to the descendant which still requires unchecked cast.  See my answer below, I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two generic parameters to your `BaseView` class, and cast `this` to `V`:

```
open class Presenter<V> {
    fun bind(v: V) {}
}

open class BaseView<P, V> where P : Presenter<V> {
  lateinit var presenter: P

  fun onStart() {
    p.bind(this as V)
  }
}
```

You would use this like

```
class FolderPresenter : Presenter<FolderChooserView>() {

}

class FolderChooserView : BaseView<FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()
```

Unfortunately, you won't get any help from your compiler if you mix up the parameters, due to the unchecked cast:

```
class SomeOtherView : BaseView<SomeOtherPresenter, FolderChooserView>()
```

Comment: Hm, I don't like this. I am thinking about designing this as a general Library so I really want to avoid these kinds of unchecked casts. Is there no solution to what I want to achieve?

Comment: I have dealt with this as well, and had a proper solution, which turned out to be way to complex. See [Presenter](https://github.com/nhaarman/Triad/blob/44c20dbf44006bf4d0c0962d382f2daa4dfe75fd/triad/src/main/java/com/nhaarman/triad/Presenter.java),  [Container](https://github.com/nhaarman/Triad/blob/44c20dbf44006bf4d0c0962d382f2daa4dfe75fd/triad/src/main/java/com/nhaarman/triad/Container.java) and the base [RelativeLayoutContainer](https://github.com/nhaarman/Triad/blob/44c20dbf44006bf4d0c0962d382f2daa4dfe75fd/triad/src/main/java/com/nhaarman/triad/RelativeLayoutContainer.java) (in java).

Comment: These are files of an older version of a library of mine, where the generic types of the Presenter and View reference eachother to enforce proper behavior. Unfortunately [this requires a lot of sort of complex boilerplate](https://github.com/nhaarman/Triad/blob/44c20dbf44006bf4d0c0962d382f2daa4dfe75fd/triad-sample/app/src/main/java/com/nhaarman/triad/sample/notes/noteslist/NoteView.java).

Comment: This cast isn't such a bad thing, there are not a lot of good answers for this if any.  You can always add an assert that gives a really direct error message and since these happen immediately when an activity is created, you'll see the error very early in testing.

Comment: Yes, that's why I chose to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @nhaarman is close but leaves open the hole if the class being bound is not actually the type of the view.

This cast isn't such a bad thing, there are not a lot of good answers for this if any. You can always add an assert that gives a really direct error message and since these happen immediately when an activity is created, you'll see the error very early in testing

I don't think you'll easily get to a better answer without creating something that manages all parts of the relationship as one.  I think his answer has minimal risk.

**Compile time checking to avoid runtime error**

You could write a function that can check the missing piece at compile time and people could use it like a compile-time assert.

```
// a function that is used when people want to check validity at compile time,
// it does nothing but cause compiler error if wrong heirarchy

fun <A: V, P: Presenter<V>, V : View> checkValid() {
    // empty on purpose, used for compile time check
}

// successful:
checkValid<FolderChooserActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()

// error below: "Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'test.so.FolderChooserView'"
checkValid<TryingToFoolItActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()

// this is blocked because SomeOtherActivity has its own compiler error so SomeOtherActivity type is not fully known
checkValid<SomeOtherActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()
```

**Using a function to create the class, with compile time checking to avoid runtime error**

You can also require that a function be used to construct the `*Activity` class.  But if you can't enforce people ensuring they have the right view base class, you can't enforce the use of this function.  Here it is anyway, just to give more ideas to this problem.

```
inline fun <reified A: V, P: Presenter<V>, V : View> makeActivity(): A {
    return A::class.java.newInstance() 
}

// successful:
val good1 = makeActivity<FolderChooserActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()

// error below: "Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'test.so.FolderChooserView'"
val bad1 = makeActivity<TryingToFoolItActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()
```

**Full code:**

I'm putting full code here so I can explore this more and try to get an alternative complete answer.  This is really just a variation of @nhaarman's answer.

```
// sample classes

class FolderPresenter : Presenter<FolderChooserView>() { }

class BadPresenter : Presenter<RandomView>() { }

// successful declaration
class FolderChooserActivity : BaseActivity<FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>(), FolderChooserView { }

// Error: "Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'test.so.Presenter<test.renlearn.solrpref.FolderChooserView>'"
class SomeOtherActivity : BaseActivity<BadPresenter, FolderChooserView>(), FolderChooserView {}

// Runtime error, we are not a FolderChooserView
class TryingToFoolItActivity : BaseActivity<FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>() {}

// now the version using a function to construct the activity, where
// this function adds the missing step of compiler time validation.

inline fun <reified A: V, P: Presenter<V>, V : View> makeActivity(): A {
    return A::class.java.newInstance()
}

// or a function that is used when people want to check validity at compile time,
// it does nothing but cause compiler error if wrong heirarchy

fun <A: V, P: Presenter<V>, V : View> checkValid() {
    // empty on purpose, used for compile time check
}

public fun foo() {
    // successful:
    val good1 = makeActivity<FolderChooserActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()

    // error below: "Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'test.so.FolderChooserView'"
    val bad1 = makeActivity<TryingToFoolItActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()

    // this is blocked because SomeOtherActivity has its own compiler error so SomeOtherActivity type is not fully known
    val bad2 = makeActivity<SomeOtherActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()

    // successful:
    checkValid<FolderChooserActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()

    // error below: "Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'test.so.FolderChooserView'"
    checkValid<TryingToFoolItActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()

    // this is blocked because SomeOtherActivity has its own compiler error so SomeOtherActivity type is not fully known
    checkValid<SomeOtherActivity, FolderPresenter, FolderChooserView>()
}
```